# Overlapping of one view on the other view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx framework. I want to design an interface such like,
overlapping of one view on the other view when I click on tab. It is some thing like in the Visual Studio we have "sourceControl" and "TeamExplorer" in the rightmost with vertical direction.

When I click on the Source control that is expanded and overlap on the existing page, and that expanded view we can scroll the width. I used dhtmlx tabs and I have to implement the same operation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The part of Visual Studio UI that you described is similar to [dhtmlxWindows](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxWindows/index.shtml). And you can use Tabbar for vertical tabs, but you should disable content zone for it:

```
tabbar.enableContentZone(false);
```

Comment: I used vertical tabs and for loading the content in the tab used tabbar.setContentHref();after giving tabbar.enableContentZone(false);
 one my content is not displaying after clicking on the tab.